# AlertDialog and soft keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am developing an android application. I am using the alertDialog class. Where I have a custom listview and 2 buttons. In my custom listview I have an EditText Field. But when the dialog pops and I touch the EditText while the cursor starts flashing in the Textbox the softKeyboard doesn't appear. Is it because of the alertdialog?

```
public class ProgressReport extends ListActivity {

private ResultSet receivedData;
private StudentProgressAdapter ca;
private Button btnRtn;
ArrayList<String> content =new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> subContent = new ArrayList<String>();
AlertDialog dialog ;


 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);         
        setContentView(R.layout.examslayout);
        

        
        for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
          content.add("ELEMENTARY: "+i);
        
          for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
              subContent.add("ΒΑΣΙΚΗ ΚΑΤΗΓΟΡΙΑ");
          
          
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Student Stats").setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    //MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
              })
            .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });;

            ListView modeList = new ListView(this);

            modeList.setAdapter(new ProgressReportAdapter2(this, new int[]{R.layout.arrowlistview}, new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2},content,20,subContent));

            builder.setView(modeList);
            
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);
            
        Intent intent = getIntent();      
        receivedData =  (ResultSet) intent.getSerializableExtra("SentData");
        
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>(MainPagerActivity.receivedData.getStudents().length);
        for (int i=0; i <receivedData.getStudents().length; i++)
              content.add(receivedData.getStudents()[i].getProperty(3).toString()+" "+receivedData.getStudents()[i].getProperty(2).toString());
        
        ca= new StudentProgressAdapter(this, new int[]{R.layout.stdprgrlistview}, new int[]{R.id.textView1}, content,content.size());
        setListAdapter(ca); 
        
        btnRtn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btnRtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            public void onClick(View v) {     
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
 
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {    
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: yes.It doesn't appear when i dismiss the alertDialog.And in an other activity it appears correctly.Yes I'll be providing the code in a while

Comment: I face the similar problem before, you can read this document:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft , maybe can help you.

Comment: Witch List contains the EditText, modeList on the AlertDialog or the main ListView ?

Comment: modeList.setAdapter(new ProgressReportAdapter2(this, new int[]{R.layout.arrowlistview}, new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2},content,20,subContent));

The arrowlistview.xml has it

Comment: @dreamtale well I've put the stateAlwayVisible option on.When i started the activity the softkeyboard appeared but when the dialog appeared the keyboard stayed on the background.

Comment: @libathos try *stateVisible* or force show soft keyboard programmatically.

Comment: I've just did it and it appeared on the background

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog alertToShow = alert.create();
alertToShow.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
alertToShow.show();
```

*Update:*

you can modify your code like this

```
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
dialog.show();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @libathos Try OnFocusChangeListener

Comment: well you mean to put your code into this listener right?I've just done that and it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

After the creation of the dialog add :

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);`
```